# how to force target in a mermaid node with a url

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I am writing a readme file in github including mermaid flow charts

Some nodes include a link:

TRIGGER[[PUSH to core-images
TAG core-images
 CLICK ME]];
click TRIGGER "https://git.XXX.org/.../main.yml"

It works but when clicking the page would be seen enbeded in the github page.
how can I force there that the page is opened in a new tab